# Tablespace Segments and Schema Objects

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I am learning about tablespaces, but I am not sure what a segment of a tablespace constitutes. Is it safe to say that the following query displays all schema objects that can be moved to different tablespaces:

```
select distinct segment_type
from dba_segments;
```

Result:

```
SEGMENT_TYPE
------------------
LOBINDEX
INDEX PARTITION
TABLE SUBPARTITION
ROLLBACK
TABLE PARTITION
NESTED TABLE
LOB PARTITION
LOBSEGMENT
INDEX
TABLE
TYPE2 UNDO
CLUSTER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segment represents the [storage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/logical-storage-structures.html) associated with an object such as a table or index. Segments reside in tablespaces.

You probably won't be moving rollback or undo segments, as those will be in their own dedicated tablespace and are system-managed in recent versions of Oracle.

I don't think there is a convenient way to move a cluster to a new tablespace, but then aside from the ones used internally for the data dictionary they are rarely used, so probably you won't have to deal with those either.